# Strip all tag except inside <Pre

Tags: php, strip-tags

I have a string.

```
$string = '<p>someText</p><li>someText</li><pre><p>someText</p></pre>';
I
```

want strip all tags except inside pre tag.
for example output of $string is :

```
$string = 'someTextsomeText<pre><p>someText</p></pre>';
```

this is not working:

```
$string = strip_tags($string,<pre>);
```

Comment: A p element isn’t allowed inside a pre element so if you **don’t** strip tags you are going to have invalid HTML.

Comment: `strip_tags` will not do what you need. You need to find another solution. How that would look like really is up to you there are many many ways you can approach this (e.g. run `strip_tags` only on the substrings outside of `<pre>...</pre>` or replace `<pre>...</pre>` with placeholders and then replace them back etc).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution - with an example string as:

```
$string = '<p>some Text First</p><li>some Text First</li><pre><p>someTextInside</p></pre><p>Some Text Last</p>';
```

Make pattern to find pre and contents within:

```
$pattern="/\<pre>(.*?)<\/pre>/";
```

Use preg_match to find patter:

```
$preSection = preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
```

Split into parts BEFORE pre and AFTER pre:

```
$parts = explode($matches[0], $string);
```

Strip Tags from content before pre and after pre and combine together to final string:

```
$final = strip_tags($parts[0]) . $matches[0] . strip_tags($parts[1]);

echo $final;

// RESULT: some Text Firstsome Text First<pre><p>someTextInside</p></pre>Some Text Last
```